# multivariate geometric brownian motion equivalent martingale measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingale, geometric-brownian

Suppose $W$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motion and the process $S$ follows a geometric $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motion model with respect to $W$. $S$ is given by
\begin{equation} 
dS(t) = S(t)\big((\mu - r)dt + \sigma dW(t)\big)
\end{equation}
where $\mu, r, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$.
Thanks to Girsanov theorem, we know that $S$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-martingale for $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}} = \mathcal{E}\Big(\int \lambda dW\Big)
\end{equation}
where $\lambda = \frac{\mu - r}{\sigma}$.

This is the case where the Brownian motion and $S$ are one dimensional. What can be said about multivariate case ?

I tried something :
When $W$ is $d$-dimensional and $S$ is $n$-dimensional, with $n, d \geq 1$, $\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}$, $S$ is given by
\begin{equation}
dS_i(t) = S_i(t)\big((\mu_i -r)dt + \sum_{i = 1}^d \sigma_{ij}dW_j(t)\big)
\end{equation}
If we define $\lambda$ as
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{ij} = \frac{\mu_i - r}{\sigma_{ij}d}
\end{equation}
Maybe somehow we could use Girsanov theorem in a similar way as before to find a probability measure such that $S$ is a martingale ? I cannot find a way to do this properly. The problem is that with this approach, for each $i \leq n$, we only find a measure under which $S_i$ is a martingale, but I am not sure how to deduce a result for $S$.

edit : Is it enough to take each $i \leq n$ individually, find a measure $\mathbb{Q}_i$ under which $S_i$ is a martingale by using the approach I mentioned before, and then say that $S$ is a martingale under the product measure $\otimes_{i \leq n} \mathbb{Q}_i$ ? According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85616/definition-of-multivariate-martingale), a sufficient condition for a multivariate process to be a martingale is if each component separately is a martingale.

Thank you in advance for your help.